# Search file by user input file name in a specific folder exist or not?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to build a program which allow user to enter any name and it will search in specific defined folder. If named file exist in folder then it shows file exist otherwise not exist.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class FindFile 
{
    public void findFile(String name,File file)
    {
        File[] list = file.listFiles();
        if(list!=null)
        for (File fil : list)
        {
            if (fil.isDirectory())
            {
                findFile(name,fil);
            }
            else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(fil.getName()))
            {
                System.out.println(fil.getParentFile());
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FindFile ff = new FindFile();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the file to be searched.. " );
        String name = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the directory where to search ");
        String directory = scan.next();
        ff.findFile(name,new File(directory));
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you want it to search the folder name instead of the file name?

Comment: NO I WANT TO SEARCH FILE NAME IN FOLDER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Question is not clear.
With **your** code you get **all Files** in the **specific** folder and also from the **child folders**

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FindFile ff = new FindFile();
    String name = "notepad.exe";
    String directory ="C:\\Windows\\";

    ff.findFile(name,new File(directory));

    System.out.println("---------------");
}
```

Output:

> C:\Windows\notepad.exe
>   C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
>   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe
>   C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-notepadwin_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_9ebebe8614be1470\notepad.exe
>   .-----------------------------------------------

If you want to search for a file in **one** folder (not deeper)
and you are on a **NOT** case sensitive **OS**

> OP :
>   User enter file name then it Search in Specific folder if Exist Or
>   Not..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "notepad.exe";
    String path ="C:\\Windows\\";
    File f = new File(path+"\\"+filename);
    if(f.exists() && f.isFile()) { 
      System.out.println(path+file+" : found");
    }  

    System.out.println("---------------");        
}
```

Output:

> C:\Windows\notepad.exe : found
>   .---------------

If you want in one folder to search for case sensitive file names
change the findFile() code to

```
public void findFile(String name,File file)
  {
       File[] list = file.listFiles();
       if(list!=null) {
        for (File fil : list)
        {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(fil.getName()))
            {
                System.out.println(fil.getParentFile()+"\\"+name);
            }
        }
       }
  }
```

---

**UPDATE**

Put this in your main and replace the search terms with what you are looking for.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "notepad.exe";
    String path ="C:\\Windows";
    File f = new File(path+"\\"+filename);
    if(f.exists() && f.isFile()) { 
        System.out.println(path+filename+" : found");
    } else {
        System.out.println(path+filename+" : not found");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Looking at your code 
With three new components

**jButton3

jsearchText

jLabel3**

you can use and expand it to your own "Form dialog".

[image]

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      searchtext = jsearchText.getText();
      File f = new File(searchtext);
    if(f.exists() && f.isFile()) {
        jLabel3.setText("found : "+searchtext);
    } else {
        jLabel3.setText("not found : "+searchtext);
    }
    }
```

**UPDATE 3**

To your question : checks with multi extension

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fullPath;
    String pathSeparator = "\\";
    String extSeparator = ".";
    String path = "U:\\Grafik\\Stack\\testExt\\";
    String filename = "Pic24.gif";
    String searchtext;    
    String[] elements = { ".jpg",".png",".jpeg"};           
    fullPath = path+filename;
    int dot = fullPath.lastIndexOf(extSeparator);
    searchtext = fullPath.substring(0, dot);

    for (String s: elements) {           
        File f = new File(searchtext+s);
          if(f.exists() && f.isFile()) {
           System.out.println("found : "+searchtext+s);
          } else {
           System.out.println("not found : "+searchtext+s);
          }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually i didnt write correctly the question...i want to search a .jpg file in a specfic folder..so its like this...enter file name xyz.jpg...if file found in that folder print file found else not found...and also with multi extension is it possible like it search too for .png .jpeg .jpg

Comment: @PankajPatidar : And what is the problem with my answer? You will find the file with just `File f = new File(path+"\\"+file);
       if(f.exists() && f.isFile()) { 
       System.out.println(path+file);
       }`

Comment: Below Link Contains Source Code Of My Project..Will You Check Where I Misplaced The Code...Where Is Right Place To Place Code Please.. -------------------------------- pastebin.com/TNNKqFFZ -------------------------------- Please Solve My This Issue :(

Comment: @PankajPatidar : I can not see any related code at paste bin. `public void findFile` is not there ! So I can not help ! You Question . Look at my updated answer. put it in your main part.

Comment: `String filename = "notepad.exe";

    String path ="C:\\Windows";

    File f = new File(path+"\\"+filename);

    if(f.exists() && f.isFile()) { 
        System.out.println(path+filename+" : found");
    } else {
        System.out.println(path+filename+" : not found");
    }
}`

@moskito-x : This Code Is Working But in this code we specify that to search notepad.exe (here i want any xyz file name entered by user and that file name it search in that location)

Comment: UPDATE : 
`String filename = "notepad.exe";

    String path ="C:\\Windows";

    File f = new File(path+"\\"+filename);

    if(f.exists() && f.isFile()) { 
        System.out.println(path+filename+" : found");
    } else {
        System.out.println(path+filename+" : not found");
    }
}`

@moskito-x : This Code Is Working But in this code we specify that to search notepad.exe (here i want any xyz file name entered by user in **TEXTFIELD** and when click on button , it checks file exist or not in that location)

Comment: Source Code : [LINK TO SOURCE CODE PASTE BIN](http://pastebin.com/7b4AUqDq) See This Link And There I PAste Source Code Of My Project

Comment: thanks @moskito-x my problem is solved by your code...can we just search a file without entering its extension ? And also it checks with multi extension..jpg , jpeg,png..

Comment: @PankajPatidar : Look at update 3 in my answer :-) . To clean up : Please Delete your long comments (with code in it).

Comment: Not Working It Always Show Not Found File !
`String fullPath;
String pathSeparator = "\\";
String extSeparator = ".";
String path = "E:\\Identity\\";
String filename = jTextField1.getText();
String searchtext;    
String[] elements = { ".jpg",".png",".jpeg"};           
fullPath = path+filename;
int dot = fullPath.lastIndexOf(extSeparator);
searchtext = fullPath.substring(0, dot);
for (String s: elements) {           
File f = new File(searchtext+s);
if (f.exists() && f.isFile()) {
jTextField2.setText("Identity Found");
} else {
jTextField2.setText("Identity Not Found !");
}
}`

Comment: @PankajPatidar : It works but you must either change the code to test for trailing backslash `\\` or user enter the path with backslash at the end. Like C:\windows\ that's all. PLEASE delete the  **answer** you wrote and delete the **comments** with code int it.